# List of acronyms not created

Tags: glossaries

I am working on a paper and tried to include an acronym file. 
So what I did for that so far is:

1. Including glossaries package in the header protion of my document: `\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}`
2. Including a `\makeglossaries` in the header.
3. Including my acronyms file and a printglossaries in the actual document: `\input{acronyms}

   \printglossaries`

Running makeglossaries script shows the following:

```
makeglossaries template_diplomarbeit  
added glossary type 'acronym' (alg,acr,acn)  
makeindex  -s "template_diplomarbeit.ist" -t "template_diplomarbeit.alg" -o "template_diplomarbeit.acr" "template_diplomarbeit.acn"  
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [20-Nov-2007] (kpathsea + Thai support).  
Scanning style file ./template_diplomarbeit.ist...........................done   (27 attributes redefined, 1 ignored).  
Scanning input file template_diplomarbeit.acn....done (18 entries accepted, 0 rejected).  
Sorting entries....done (75 comparisons).  
Generating output file template_diplomarbeit.acr....done (45 lines written, 0 warnings).  
Output written in template_diplomarbeit.acr.  
Transcript written in template_diplomarbeit.alg.  
makeindex  -s "template_diplomarbeit.ist" -t "template_diplomarbeit.glg" -o "template_diplomarbeit.gls" "template_diplomarbeit.glo"  
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [20-Nov-2007] (kpathsea + Thai support).  
Scanning style file ./template_diplomarbeit.ist...........................done   (27 attributes redefined, 1 ignored).  
Scanning input file template_diplomarbeit.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).  
Nothing written in template_diplomarbeit.gls.  
Transcript written in template_diplomarbeit.glg.
```

The result is no glossary or acronyms included anywhere.

However when I include the glossaries package without the acronym option (=acronyms are included in the glossary instead of giving them their own list) my list of acronyms shows up.

Comment: `Scanning input file template_diplomarbeit.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).` there are no entries in the `.glo` file. The acronym file seems to be ok. Create a small example file which defines an entry for the glossary.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand this correctly you still need to *use* the acronyms in the document with macros like `\gls` or `\glslink`. The entries in the *acronyms* file only *define* the acronyms, but only the one which are actually used in the document will be listed.

The idea behind this is that you can have a central *acronyms* definition file used by many different documents, but only the one you actually use in the current document are really displayed. Its the same for `.bib` file and BibTeX.

See the [glossaries manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries.pdf), especially section 1.4 Q10 on page 22, for more information.

Comment: The weird thing is that there _are_ uses of the glossary entries. However the files using them get inlined to the doucment (via `input`) after the printglossaries. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @er4z0r: The position of `\printglossaries` should not be the issue. More important is where you define the entries. They should be defined before they are used, best in the preamble. As @Herbert already mentioned it is best to make a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that/231#231) to show how you using the glossaries macros.

Comment: is there an analogue of `\nocite{*}` for acronyms?

Comment: @Seamus: With the `glossaries` package it is `\glsaddall`.